# BackgroundTask deferral.Complete

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

My question is, what does the `deferral.complete()` method exactly, does this method call the event `task.Compledet`, or is there a way to call a method from the `BackgroundTaskSyncer` in my class `BackgroundSyncer` ????
When i run the Programm i will do the Run method from BackgroundTaskSyncer but nothing in the other class??

```
    namespace NotificationTask
            {
                public sealed class BackgroundTaskSyncer : IBackgroundTask
                {
                    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
                    {
                        BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
                        deferral.Complete();
                    }
                }
                }
    namespace Services
    {

    public static class BackgroundSync
        {
    private static async Task RegisterBackgroundTask()
            {
                try
                {
                    BackgroundAccessStatus status = await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
                    if (status == BackgroundAccessStatus.AllowedWithAlwaysOnRealTimeConnectivity || status == BackgroundAccessStatus.AllowedMayUseActiveRealTimeConnectivity)
                    {
                        bool isRegistered = BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks.Any(x => x.Value.Name == "Notification task");
                        if (!isRegistered)
                        {
                            BackgroundTaskBuilder builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder
                            {
                                Name = "Notification task",
                                TaskEntryPoint =
                                    "NotificationTask.BackgroundTaskSyncer"
                            };
                            builder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15, false));
                            builder.AddCondition(new SystemCondition(SystemConditionType.InternetAvailable));
                            BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();
                            task.Completed += new BackgroundTaskCompletedEventHandler(OnCompleted);
                            task.Progress += new BackgroundTaskProgressEventHandler(OnProgress);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The access has already been granted");
                }
            }
    private static void OnCompleted(IBackgroundTaskRegistration task, BackgroundTaskCompletedEventArgs args)
            {
                ToTheBackGroundWork();
            }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deferrals were created to work around a problem with `async void` events and methods. For example, if you had to `await` during a background operation, you would use an `async void Run` method. But the problem with that is that the runtime has no idea that you actually have more work you want to do.

So, a deferral is an object that you can use to inform the runtime "I'm really done now." A deferral is only necessary if you need to `await`.

I have a [blog post that goes into "asynchronous event handlers" and deferrals in more detail](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/02/async-oop-5-events.html).